# SP 2010 wiki anchors

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer, anchor-tags

I was wondering if there was any way to make anchors in a wiki that work properly. If not, any alternatives.

I am fleshing out a wiki on a SharePoint2010 intranet site and am trying to make a table of contents for a lengthy page. When I set up anchors, clicked links go to that named anchor but it breaks the page and the scroll bar. It repositions the page so that everything above the anchor is beyond the top of the browser window. It also introduces an odd breaking point in the scroll bar that looks like an additional inactive scroll bar.

I am on IE9 and SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

Several searches have lead my down dead ends...